# Connecting GPU chips in order to create more powerful graphic card

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, interconnect, gpu

I had thoughts about GPU and I came up with an idea. Why not putting more than one GPU chips in order to create a powerful graphic card? Is it possible with ordinary GPU chips or one need custom hardware? If it's possible how to interconnect this chips on the PCB? Just theoretical question.

Comment: They have been doing this for a while now, you can link up cards (chips) and get double the processing power.

Comment: [Scalable Link Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface)

Comment: Ok. In that case I must catch up with my knowledge because I hadn't follow topic for some time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We had multiple chips on 3D graphics card all the way back to Vodoo 1 and Voodoo². Please use wikipedia *first* before asking questions.

Comment: [A Quick History of Multi-GPU Video Cards](http://www.pcgamer.com/quick-history-multi-gpu-video-cards-2014/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphics Processors do have special architecture to allow massive parallelizm of operations. The units must be fed with stream of data, yet the results of 3D processing must blend/merge into final image. To make more than one GPU on a PCB, the chips must be specifically designed to provide this expandability in terms interconnect and data sharing. Whether this re-partitioning is economically and technologically feasible and/or effective from performance standpoint is the question. The entire topic was extensively researched by finest Computer Architects for years, see, for example, this [AMD publication](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Michael_Doggett/talks/2008GeorgiaTech.pdf). The resulting manufacturing strategy is constantly evolving with progress of technology. Just throwing an "idea" to have "more" is not mature.